# Taguchi crossed array design creation and analysis

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to create the following Taguchi Crossed Array Design in R.

[image]

```
Table12.1Inner <- FrF2::FrF2(nruns = 8,  generators = "ABC", randomize = FALSE)
Table12.1Outer <- DoE.base::fac.design(nlevels = 2,  nfactors=1, factor.names = "E", randomize = FALSE)
Error in fac.design(nlevels = c(4)) : 
  one factor only is not covered by fac.design

DoE.base::cross.design(Table12.1Inner, Table12.1Outer)
```

So I am unable to create outer array design.

Comment: Can you explain or give a link to what a Taguchi Crossed Array design is?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `expand.grid`:

```
expand.grid(A = vals, B = vals, C = vals, D = vals, E.neg = 0, E.pos = 0, y = 0, sdev = 0)


   A B C D E.neg E.pos y sdev
1  + + + +     0     0 0    0
2  - + + +     0     0 0    0
3  + - + +     0     0 0    0
4  - - + +     0     0 0    0
5  + + - +     0     0 0    0
6  - + - +     0     0 0    0
7  + - - +     0     0 0    0
8  - - - +     0     0 0    0
9  + + + -     0     0 0    0
10 - + + -     0     0 0    0
11 + - + -     0     0 0    0
12 - - + -     0     0 0    0
13 + + - -     0     0 0    0
14 - + - -     0     0 0    0
15 + - - -     0     0 0    0
16 - - - -     0     0 0    0
```